# Skip SAP GUI script code line if session.findById doesn't exist

Tags: sap-gui

I recorded SAP GUI script for transaction code S_ALR_87013336.

When executing it, some users get a pop up window to insert Controlling Area:

```
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub:SAPLSPO4:0300/ctxtSVALD-VALUE[0,21]").Text = Datex6
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub:SAPLSPO4:0300/ctxtSVALD-VALUE[0,21]").caretPosition = 4
```

but for some inserting Controlling Area is not needed and with mentioned code they are getting an error.

Can code be modified to skip those two lines if Controlling Area window doesn't pop up?

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nS_ALR_87013336"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub:SAPLSPO4:0300/ctxtSVALD-VALUE[0,21]").Text = Datex6
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub:SAPLSPO4:0300/ctxtSVALD-VALUE[0,21]").caretPosition = 4
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtPAR_19").Text = Datex5
```

Comment: As `FindById` triggers an exception when the element is not found, this question can be turned into how to catch exceptions in VBA or VBScript (it has been already asked in Stack Overflow). Moreover you can find many questions tagged "sap-gui" about "Control not found", whose code does catch exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comment there are some posts regarding this topic. My suggestion in your case would be to check for the window name

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub:SAPLSPO4:0300/ctxtSVALD-VALUE[0,21]").Text = Datex6
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub:SAPLSPO4:0300/ctxtSVALD-VALUE[0,21]").caretPosition = 4
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtPAR_19").Text = Datex5
```

Further reading [Gui session object](https://help.sap.com/docs/sap_gui_for_windows/b47d018c3b9b45e897faf66a6c0885a8/a4e022f6c155414d9c8ae8eba422cac5.html?version=760.02&locale=en-US)